# Update informatica session properties using unix

Tags: bash, unix, informatica-powercenter

I have requirement where I will create a mapping manually and
 I will use unix to create task and workflow and update sessions properties with some default values.

Comment: loader connection im able to udpate but here worklfow i have created manually

Comment: Do you need to use command line tools to create the workflow? Why? Can you elaborate on the requirements?

Comment: Hi Marek  req is we will create mapping and im trying to write a script which will create workflow and update the connection details for all the lookups and check in some options like insert,delete and truncate and load , ... some session properties throught that script . so with this script i can decrease time taken to create workflow and give all those details

Answer (score 0):

One usually doesn't modify or even create informatica mappings/sessions/workflows using simple unix tools. If you need to modify certain parameters, you better use parameter files, which you can modify using the standard unix tools or even create dynamically using Informatica.

Comment: my main intention is not just to create mapping. i am thinking to write a  the script that can update the connection ,paths and some sessions properties because some of out mappings have many lkp's so we are updating them manually it is time taking.

Comment: Then use parameter files. That's what they are for.